# Google Apps Script: print, open or download as PDF a Google Doc?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google Form that will run on submit a script to dynamically generate a google doc. So far so good.

What I miss is a way to either print the document or preview document (Google doc preview) or download the document

I am aware that the script is running in the cloud, however I wonder if is there a trick to overcome this problem, allowing the script to interact with the browser.

Comment: What about sending it, or sharing the link to the doc, by email to the connected user ? That will let user choose to consult or download it...

Comment: I thought about that, but I'd rather offer one of the options above.... I am investigating Cloud printing....

Comment: From a Google Form hosted on Google Forms, you can't do much. From your own site (where the user browser has just submitted a form), you can add additional steps to the submission process, such as accessing the associated document and experimentation it as PDF. There are existing questions that cover export; you must review them yourself.